# how to install windows 7 as it already has ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, lts

i m getting a prob. to install windows 7 on ubuntu 12.04
whem i am staring the installation from a pen drive
it shows the error 0x800700A on it
how to get rid of it

Comment: try to create bootable windows usb using winusb.see this http://askubuntu.com/a/381560/202806

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting your pendrive and re-install Windows using proper version of winusb.  Then follow the steps below.

1) You should allocate the space of Windows 7 (min 20GB)

- Open the terminal and type *gparted*
- If not installed, please install using

  `sudo apt-get install gparted`
- Partition a disk where you need to install Windows 7

2) Insert the Windows 7 CD and install it and the drive allocated for windows. After installation, the windows boot loader will override the grub, so there will not be any menu listing for choosing Ubuntu.

3) Insert the live CD of any Ubuntu distribution and run the following commands in the terminal.

`sudo mount /dev/<device_name> /mnt`      #device_name of Ubuntu installation (ex. sda3)
`sudo rm -rf /boot`
`sudo ln -s /mnt/boot /boot`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install grub-pc`
`sudo grub-install /dev/sda`    #no device number here
`sudo umount /boot`

4) Restart the device. It should work fine.